# How to add text to the element as pseudo-element

Tags: html, css

I would like to add some text to the first and last element of classname .note.
I was thinking about some pseudo elements like before and after.
I guess, i need to do something like that:

.note:first-child { STYLE }

```css
.wrap{
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:row;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content:space-around;
}
.note{
  width:50px;
  height: 50px;
  background:red;
  border-radius: 50px;
  display:flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class='wrap'>
  <div class='note'>
    1
  </div>
    <div class='note'>
    2
  </div>
    <div class='note'>
    3
  </div>
    <div class='note'>
    4
  </div>
    <div class='note'>
    5
  </div>
    <div class='note'>
    6
  </div>
    <div class='note'>
    7
  </div>
    <div class='note'>
    8
  </div>
    <div class='note'>
    9
  </div>
    <div class='note'>
    10
  </div>
</div>
```

So, how can i do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `content` property of `::before` and `::after`:

```css
.note:first-of-type::after {
    content: 'first';
}
.note:last-of-type::after {
    content: 'last';
}
```

With your snippet:

```css
.wrap{
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:row;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content:space-around;
}
.note{
  width:50px;
  height: 50px;
  background:red;
  border-radius: 50px;
  display:flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.note:first-of-type::after {
  content: 'first';
}
.note:last-of-type::after {
  content: 'last';
}

/* To position the labels beneath each item, as you asked in the comments: */

.note {
  position: relative;
}

.note::after {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  text-align: center;
  bottom: -2em;
}
```

```html
<div class='wrap'>
  <div class='note'>
    1
  </div>
    <div class='note'>
    2
  </div>
    <div class='note'>
    3
  </div>
    <div class='note'>
    4
  </div>
    <div class='note'>
    5
  </div>
    <div class='note'>
    6
  </div>
    <div class='note'>
    7
  </div>
    <div class='note'>
    8
  </div>
    <div class='note'>
    9
  </div>
    <div class='note'>
    10
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I would like to have this text right below, first and last element. So i need to use position absolute, top,left etc?

Comment: @Rick exactly. Pseudo-elements can have `position: absolute` as well as everything else you need.

Comment: @Rick , nop use ::after instead and eventually display:block,

Comment: Please see the edit, I added the required properties to position is as you wanted

Comment: why so complicated? Simply use the recommended `display: block` that does not requie any positioning.

Comment: @tacoshy Add an example, just adding `display: block` does nothing (as `.note` is a flexbox container)